# Virtual File System and Areas

Tags: asp.net-mvc-areas, abp

I'm trying to use Areas in my ASP.NET Core ABP project like so:

[Folder Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1UVzI.png)

I'm trying to add a single file bundle like this:

`<abp-script src="/Areas/Community/Pages/Mentors/Index.js" />`

When I try running the page I get the following error:

`AbpException: Could not find the bundle file '/Areas/Community/Pages/Mentors/Index.js' from IWebContentFileProvider`

The documentation says the files can be located in Pages, Views, Components, and Themes but it seems limiting if it doesn't also support areas. Do I need to add a route somewhere so the virtual file system can find it?

Update:
I found the source code in \Volo.Abp.AspNetCore\Volo\Abp\AspNetCore\VirtualFileSystem\AbpAspNetCoreContentOptions.cs

where it sets the `AllowedExtraWebContentFolders` list:

```
AllowedExtraWebContentFolders = new List<string>
{
    "/Pages",
    "/Views",
    "/Themes",
    "/Components"
};
```

Is there any way to add to this list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can configure it in the module's ConfigureServices method.

```cs
public override void ConfigureServices(ServiceConfigurationContext context)
{
    Configure<AbpAspNetCoreContentOptions>(options =>
    {
        options.AllowedExtraWebContentFolders.Add("/Areas");
    });
}
```